# Binary installation file

Tags: linux, unix, file, installation

i am not really getting an idea on how a .bin file is being created. The JDK for Linux platform ships in the form of binary executable file (jdk-6u20-linux-i586-rpm.bin); how can one create such deliverable for their own project? Please give me some directions.
Thanks,
-Vijay

Answer (score 2):

You want to **create a self-extracting installer**.  See [this linux journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818) for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i am looking something similar but on a binary file (payload.bin). I shall also try out the one suggested.